# Obtener el modelo actual que esta usando Eloquent Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, base-de-datos

Estoy realizando una implementación de un plugin, pero necesito obtener el modelo actual que esta usando laravel al realizar alguna operación... Existe alguna función o forma de "interceptar" el modelo con el que esta trabajando Eloquent en ese momento?.

Comment: Hola @Chistian Irack, [tour].También te recomiendo que leas [ask]. Podrías completar tu pregunta con el código que has intentado?

Answer (score 0):

lo que puedes hacer es agregar una función en todos lo modelos que te devuelva el nombre del modelo

```
class ModeloA extends Model
{
    public function mostrarModelo() {
       echo 'ModeloA';
    }
}
class ModeloB extends Model
{
    public function mostrarModelo() {
       echo 'ModeloB';
    }
}
```

y cuanto tengas la variable

para que te devuelva el modelo usas

```
$elto=ModeloA::find(1);
$modelo=$elto->mostrarModelo();
```